# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{(1+x)^n}$

Tags: real-analysis

$f_n(x)= \frac{x}{(1+x)^n}\quad f_n(0)=0$

pointwise convergence:  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{(1+x)^n}=x \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)^n}$ and the series is a geometric series convergent if $|x+1|>1$.

So there is pointwise convergent in $E=(-\infty-2)\cup[0,+\infty)$

The sum of the series is $S(x)=1$  for $x\ne0$ and $S(0)=0$  so if I consider $[0,+\infty)$ there is not uniform convergence.
But is there convergence on a subset of $[0,+\infty)$?

If I consider $A=[b,+\infty),b>0$  $sup_A|f_n(x)|=f_n({\frac{1}{n-1}})$ general term of a convergent series so for Weierstrass test the series uniform converges for in A

And in B=$(-\infty,-2)$: if I consider sup$_B|S(x)-S_N(x)|>$sup$_B|\sum_{n=N+1}^{+\infty}f_n(x)|$
The superior extreme is major of value of the fuction in every its point so I take $x_n=-2-{\frac{1}{n}}$ and prove there isn't convergence?

Answer (score 2):

If $S_N$ is the N-th partial sum then $S_N-1=\frac 1 {(1+x)^{N}}$ (by the formula for sum of a finite geometric sum). Hence the series converges uniformly on a set iff $|(1+x)|^{N} \to \infty$ uniformly on $S$. I think you can take it from here.

Comment: It's correct my answer up?

Answer (score 0):

The series is convergent on $x\in E, ~\text{where} ~E=(-\infty, -2)\cup [0,\infty)$

Define the parital sum as $S_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} f_k(x)$

$$S_n(x)=x\left(\frac{1}{1+x}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(1+x)^n}\right)=1-\frac{1}{(1+x)^n}$$

First check pointwise convergence

If  $x=0,~~S_n(0)=0$,

If $x\in E\cap x\neq 0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n(x)=1$.

$$
S(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if} \quad x=0 \\
1 & \text{if} \quad x\in E\cap x\neq 0
\end{cases}
$$

Since $S_n(x)$ is continous for all $n$, if $S_n(x)\to S(x)$ uniformly, then $S(x)$ is continuous.

Obviously, $S(x)$ is not continous at $0$, (by $p\to q \Leftrightarrow\neg q\to\neg p $), therefore $S_n$ is not uniformly convergent.